# Why return self in a custom iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, self

I'm relativley new to python (not coding) and I'm playing around with iterators in the language.  When we build iterators I understand **how** they work and how to build a custom iterator, but I don't understand **why** we `return self` in `__iter__(self)` function.

Here's an example:

```
class Cube_Pow:
    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max
    
    def __iter__(self):
        self.n   = 0
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            cube = self.n ** 3
            self.n += 1
            return cube
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

If I do the following:

```
cubes     = Cube_Pow(10)
cube_iter = iter(cubes)
print(cube_iter) #output: <__main__.Cube_Pow object at 0x1084e8cd0>
```

My question is shouldn't the type be some iterator (for instance list has `list_iterator`).  Do have to extend some other class?

Comment: Because iterators should be idempotent. Consider `mylist = [1,2,3]`: You want: `iterator = iter(mylist); next(iterator); for x in iterator: print(x)` to print `2, 3`, not `1,2,3` because you already started iterating over it.

Comment: Note, `iter` resetting your iterator essentially makes it broken. Once `StopIteration` has been raised, trying to iterate over it again should *always raise `StopIteration`* (although note, file iterators actually break this because `.seek` resets it... but practicality beats purity I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__iter__` makes something iterable. It returns an iterator but it is not the iterator itself. There are two approaches to iteration. An object can be its own iterator

```
>>> fileobj = open("test.txt")
>>> iter(fileobj) == fileobj
True
>>> print(type(fileobj), type(iter(fileobj)))
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

Or it can return a different object to handle the iteration

```
>>> listobj = []
>>> iter(listobj) == listobj
False
>>> print(type(listobj), type(iter(listobj)))
<class 'list'> <class 'list_iterator'>
```

You return `self` if you want all iterators of the object to iterate the same thing. That's what you want for a file which is doing sequential access under the covers. But for a list, you'd expect each iterator to start from the top again, so a new `list_iterator` object is created each time to do just that.

An iterator usually returns `self` so it is safe to call `iter()` on it again (either directly or indirectly due to a `for` loop or list comprehension or something).

Although there may be a specific reason in your case, an iterator resetting itself (`self.n = 0`) is not what you want to do. Once you get an iterator, calling `iter()` on it again shouldn't change it.

Comment: You could even point at the `iter(fileobj) is fileobj`